# Manter valor no select após navegação com NgbNav

Tags: angular, angular-8

Fala pessoal estou com um problema que não estou conseguindo compreender, tenho um componente personalizavel do tipo select, ele aparentemente funciona corretamente esta armazenando o valor do option no formControl atraves de formControlName, porém ao trocar de abas do ngbNav o select simplismente deixa de exibir o valor que antes estava selecionado já debuguei o writeValue e obj chaga corretamente porem nada é atribuido ao select novamente.Segue o código da página e do componente para simulação.

HTML code

```
 <b-select-custom id="sex" name="sex" [options]="sexs" propertyOption="description"
                                        label="Sexo" formControlName="sex" [isValid]="representativeForm.controls['sex'].errors?.['required']
                                        && representativeForm.controls['sex'].touched"></b-select-custom>
```

TS code

```
protected sexs: Array<Sex> = [{id:1, "Feminino"},{id:2, description: "Masculino"}];
representativeForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({ sex: new FormControl<string | null>(null, [Validators.required])});
```

component

HTML code

```
<div class="container-select-wrapper w-100">
    <div class="select-wrapper w-100 d-flex align-items-center" [ngClass]="{'has-value':hasValue}">
        <select [id]="id" (change)="onSelectOption($event)" class="w-100" [disabled]="disabled" (blur)="onTouched()">
            <option [value]="" selected></option>
            <option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option | json">{{option[propertyOption]}}
            </option>
        </select>
        <label [for]="id" class="floating-label">{{label}}</label>
        <img id="iconAlert" *ngIf="isValid" title="Campo obrigatório" src="\assets\icons\alert.svg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

TS code

```
import { Component, forwardRef, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALIDATORS, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, Validator } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'b-select-custom',
  templateUrl: './select-custom.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./select-custom.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => SelectCustomComponent),
      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => SelectCustomComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class SelectCustomComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, Validator {
  @Input() id!: string;
  @Input() label!: string;
  @Input() options!: any[];
  @Input() formControlName!: string;
  @Input() propertyOption!: string;
  @Input() isValid!: boolean;

  selectedOption: any;
  onChange: any;
  onTouched: any;
  hasValue: boolean = false;
  disabled: boolean = false;

  writeValue(obj: any): void {
    this.selectedOption = obj;
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn
  }

  setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    this.disabled = isDisabled;
  }

  validate(): any {
    return null;
  }

  onSelectOption(option: any): void {
    const select = (option.target as HTMLSelectElement)
    this.selectedOption = JSON.parse(select.value);
    this.hasValue = this.selectedOption != "";

    this.onChange(this.selectedOption);
    this.onTouched();
  }


}
```

Answer (score -1):

Tente implementar o lifecycle ngOnDestroy no seu componente, segue documentação: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#ondestroy

Com isso você pode marcar um ponto de interrupção no destroy para validar se o ngbNav está destruindo e reconstruindo o seu componente.

Se ele estiver destruindo este é o problema, nunca usei o ngbNav então não sei seu comportamento, mas acho valido você testar. Se quiser compartilhar o código em que criou no menu de navegação fica mais fácil de entender.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).